# What is $source and $sources in BaseRelationField?

Tags: plugin-development, relations, custom-fieldtype

I see the following in BaseRelationField:

```
public function settingsAttributes(): array
{
    $attributes = parent::settingsAttributes();
    $attributes[] = 'sources';
    $attributes[] = 'source';
    $attributes[] = 'targetSiteId';
    $attributes[] = 'viewMode';
    $attributes[] = 'limit';
    $attributes[] = 'selectionLabel';
    $attributes[] = 'localizeRelations';

    return $attributes;
}
```

The comments for the properties say:

```
   /**
     * @var string|string[]|null The source keys that this field can relate elements from (used if [[allowMultipleSources]] is set to true)
     */
    public $sources = '*';

    /**
     * @var string|null The source key that this field can relate elements from (used if [[allowMultipleSources]] is set to false)
     */
    public $source;
```

In the case of the single source. What would that string look like? What is that string referring to? A table name? In ID in a particular table?

Looks like the BaseRelationField is extended by Entries field and Users field and the sources are Entry structures and Administration groups respectively. If I wanted to set one as s static value what would that be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of the element type `Asset` sources are the available volumes. In case of `Category` the available sources are the different groups. Sources for `Entry` are your sections, `Tag` have the different sets/groups as well.

It contains an array or the type `section`, `folder`, `group` and the ID of the corresponding model, separated with an `:`

You can just do

```
$field = Craft::$app->getFields()->getFieldById(>>your field id<<);
Craft::dd($field->sources);
```

to get to know how it looks like. It could be like this:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=> string(10) "section:16"
  [1]=> string(10) "section:18"
}
```

or for an `Asset`

```
array(1) {
  [0]=> string(8) "folder:1"
}
```